# Can I rotate <Text> without transform rotate?

Tags: react-native

**Problem**

Looks like when I rotate my text or view 90 degrees it doesn't rotate the element.. So it only rotates what you see but it doesn't let the graph expand because it like the element is still there but invisible..

**Question**

Is there a way I could rotate the element? Maybe not use transform? I've clicked on every possible link that included the key words 'react native' & 'transform' & 'Rotate'.

`transform: [{ rotate: '-90deg'}],`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple CSS problem and here there is a hotfixes you can use. This approach uses the principle of using `position: "absolute"`

```
<View style={styles.container} >
    <View style={styles.rotatedTextContainer>

        <Text style={styles.rotatedText}>Testing</Text>
    </View>

    <View style={styles.graphContainer>
        <Graph style={styles.graph} />
        <Text style={styles.regularText}>Test</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```

And this is how the CSS styles will look like:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        width: '100%',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flex: 1,
    },
    rotatedTextContainer: {
        height: '100%',
        position: 'absolute',
        padding: 5,
        top: 0,
        left: 0
    }
    rotatedText: {
        transform: [{ rotate: '-90deg' }],
    },
    graphContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginLeft: 50,  
    },
    graph: {
        width: "100%", 
        height: 300
    },
    regularText: {}
})
```

This is the CSS you will need. You can add other css properties to the ones I shared above.

Hope this resolves the issue.

Comment: Tried to integrate your solution - I couldn't for the life of me get the text to properly relocate to the side of the graph.. It keeps moving to the top/center no matter what I try.